# C# - How do I remove a value from a List<Tuple>

Tags: c#, list, tuples

I have a 3-tuple `List<Tuple>` with `string, string, string`.
Initialization:
`List<Tuple<string, string string>> myTupleList = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>();`
I basically want to search for a value in `Item2` and remove the whole entry if found.
Let me visualize. If I have:

```
Item1 | Item2 | Item3
---------------------
"bar" | "foo" | "baz"
---------------------
"cat" | "dog" | "sun"
---------------------
"fun" | "bun" | "pun"
```

I want doing

```
//pseudocode
myTupleList.Remove("dog" in Item2);
```

To make the List

```
Item1 | Item2 | Item3
---------------------
"bar" | "foo" | "baz"
---------------------
"fun" | "bun" | "pun"
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have a look at the [`RemoveAll` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) of `List<T>`. It lets you remove an item based on a predicate.

For example, you can check just the `Item2` property, as you said in your question:

```
myTupleList.RemoveAll(item => item.Item2 == "dog");
```

Note that (as implied by the method name) this will remove *all* elements that match this condition. Hence, if there are several elements whose `Item2` property equals `"dog"`, all of them will be removed.

Answer (score 5):

```
myTupleList.RemoveAll( p => p.Item2 == "dog");
```